# I want to pass the array inside the dictionary parameter with URL POST method

Tags: ios, iphone, json

I am new to json, I want to pass the `NSArray` inside the `NSDictionary` as a parameter along with the url to server, how it can be done while method is `post` ? I had tried sample codes but not found my exact solution.below is my sample code

```
     NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"contact_name", @"kumar",@"designantion",@"sales", nil];
    NSDictionary *finalDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:dict, @"OfficeContactPerson", nil];



    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"name=%@&short_name=%@&shop_no=%@&door_no=%@&floor=%@&building=%@&street=%@&area=%@&main=%@&city=%@&state=%@&district=%@&pincode=%@&telephone=%@&contact_name=%@&designatio=%@&mobile=%@&email=%@&OfficeContactPerson=%@",self.txtshowroom.text,self.txtshortname.text,self.txtshop.text,self.txtdoor.text,self.txtfloor.text,self.txtbuilding.text,self.txtstreet.text,self.txtarea.text,self.txtmain.text,cityineger,stateintegervalue,districtintegervalue,self.txtpincode.text,self.txttel.text,self.txtname.text,self.txtdesign.text,self.txtmbl.text,self.txtemail.text,finalDict];

    NSLog(@"postdata :%@",post);


    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://139.59.252.34:1337/office"];
    NSData *postData=[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postlength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postlength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error=[[NSError alloc]init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response=nil;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];


if (!urlData){


    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"message:FS_ERROR_LOCALIZED_DESCRIPTION(error.code)
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
else
{
    NSString *responseData=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response data ----->%@",responseData);
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSDictionary *jsonData=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

);
}



 OfficeContactPerson": [
  {
    "office": 29,
    "contact_name": "Priya",
    "designation": "Prop",
    "department": "ALL",
    "mobile": "1231231231",
    "email": "priya@yopmail.com",
    "incharge_status": null,
    "created_by": null,
    "modified_by": null,
    "id": 14,
    "createdAt": "2016-04-19T13:43:59.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-04-19T14:25:36.000Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: convert array into Json string and send that string value over server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert array into `json` string or make dictionary of post data than convert it into `json` string and post string to server. I hope below code will work for you. This code is works fine for me-

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"contact_name", @"kumar",@"designantion",@"sales", nil];
NSDictionary *finalDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:dict, @"OfficeContactPerson", nil];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://139.59.252.34:1337/office"];
NSData *postData=[[[NSString alloc]initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:finalDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postlength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postlength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error=[[NSError alloc]init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response=nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];


if (!urlData){


    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)(error.code)]
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
else
{
    NSString *responseData=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response data ----->%@",responseData);
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSDictionary *jsonData=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];


}
```

Comment: fficeContactPerson": [
  {
    "office": 29,
    "contact_name": "Priya",
    "designation": "Prop",
    "department": "ALL",
    "mobile": "1231231231",
    "email": "priya@yopmail.com",
    "incharge_status": null,
    "created_by": null,
    "modified_by": null,
    "id": 14,
    "createdAt": "2016-04-19T13:43:59.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-04-19T14:25:36.000Z"
  }
]

Comment: hw cn i pass the above dat

Comment: is this dictionary or array ?

Comment: array inside dictionary

Comment: your above 'post' string is not in correct json formate which you are post to server. Make a key/value pair for each data using dictionary like you have done in your first line of code.

Comment: i have make a key value pair for each an then i have passed in the post string ..but still shows same error will u please help me

Comment: if your final dictionary is ready then convert this dictionary to json string using--    NSString *postArrayJsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:yourDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: iam getting an error like -1005 connection was lost this problem occuring when iam using key value pairs and passing into string ..if i wont doo like dat response is getting "created sucessfully"

Comment: this error may be come due to null value you are passing. Try to pass empty value in place of null.

Comment: OfficePrice: '(\n        {\n        OfficePrice =         (\n                        {\n                "amber_price" = 1;\n                "amethyst_price" = 1;\n                "cartage_price" = null;\n                "cartage_price_type" = null;\n                "credit_period" = 1;\n                "diamond_price" = 1;\n                every thing is coming like \n

Comment: bro even i have checked in the place of null value i have given 0 but still same error

Comment: i have tested your code this works fine just need some changes. I'm getting response from server.. Please check my updated answer..

Comment: there is no such error like 1005... I'm getting response from server easily. like   Response data ----->{
  "err": {
    "error": "E_VALIDATION",
    "status": 400,
    "summary": "6 attributes are invalid",
    "model": "Office",
    "invalidAttributes": {
      "name": [
        {
          "rule": "string",
          "message": "`undefined` should be a string (instead of \"null\", which is a object)"
        },

Comment: bro tell  me how to handle dis officecontactperson is key

Comment: OfficeContactPerson": [
  {
    "office": 29,
    "contact_name": "Priya",
    "designation": "Prop",
    "department": "ALL",
    "mobile": "1231231231",
    "email": "priya@yopmail.com",
    "incharge_status": null,
    "created_by": null,
    "modified_by": null,
    "id": 14,
    "createdAt": "2016-04-19T13:43:59.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-04-19T14:25:36.000Z"
  }
]

Comment: bro code works fine.. I'm getting response from server-"err": {
    "error": "E_VALIDATION",
    "status": 400,
    "summary": "6 attributes are invalid",
    "model": "Office",
    "invalidAttributes": {
      "name":

Comment: i think there are some param missing because server response says 6 attributes are invalid. Those attribute is not in your post array. So i cant figure out what is that. Try to do as shown above with right parameters and value. Hope your problem will sovle

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in ios app development but I try to solve.lets assume that these are your string.Try this code:

```
    NSString *messages-getModuleMessages=@"messages-getModuleMessages";
NSString * authtincateToken=@"WWc3ZFZCcEtWcGxLTk1hZHhEb2hMelFNZzdGcXgwdTBxeU51NWFwUE44TnkrcnF5SCtSMDxxxxxxx";
NSString *accessSecretkey =@"WWc3ZFZCcEtWcGxLTk1hZHhEb2hMelFNZzdGcXgwdTBxeU51NWFwUE44TnkrcnF5SCtxxxxxxxx";
NSString *inboxvalue =@"hai thios is textmessage";

// this is your dictionary value are you passed
NSDictionary * callDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:messages-getModuleMessages,@"call",authtincateToken,@"authToken", accessSecretkey, @"accessSecret",inboxvalue,@"calotype",@"json",@"format",nil];

  // convert your dictionary to NSData
  NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:callDict options:kNilOptions error:nil];
 // this is your service request url
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxx"]];
 // set the content as format
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: jsonData];
  // this is your response type        
 [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
   NSError *err;
  NSURLResponse *response;
   // send the synchronous connection
   NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
   // here add your server response NSJSONSerialization
  NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err]; 

  // if u want to check the data in console
  NSString *tmp=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below line of code and put them place of first two line of line code. Problem is only there.

```
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"contact_name", @"kumar",@"designantion",@"sales", nil];
    NSDictionary *finalDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dict], @"OfficeContactPerson", nil];
NSData *POST_Params = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:urlParams options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]; // Pass these post data in request
```

Hope this will work for you!!

Comment: fficeContactPerson": [ { "office": 29, "contact_name": "Priya", "designation": "Prop", "department": "ALL", "mobile": "1231231231", "email": "priya@yopmail.com", "incharge_status": null, "created_by": null, "modified_by": null, "id": 14, "createdAt": "2016-04-19T13:43:59.000Z", "updatedAt": "2016-04-19T14:25:36.000Z" } ]

Comment: and also i have some of the text fields like name shop name like dat

Comment: br0 officecontactpersn is key then after array

Comment: In JSON [] means array and {} means dictionary. have you tried as per my answer?